# Dial number without prompt

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions, phone-call

I'm trying to write a function for the Android platform that will allow me to call 911 without any sort of prompt.

I have already added the permission `android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED`. I just need a function that will dial 911 at the press of a button in my options menu.

Comment: I can think of a few really good uses of an app like this, actually.  "Why on earth...?"  isn't a helpful comment.

Comment: Are you using the ACTION_CALL intent? Does it work?

Comment: I would consider this before rolling it out. You don't want to make it TOO easy for users to dial 911. There are already enough accidental 911 calls. If a user accidentally dials 911 once or twice they'll probably uninstall your app. It might also be nice to add a note telling the user not to hang up on a 911 call, stay on the line and tell them it's a mistake. A couple of pages that discuss this problem: http://www.911dispatch.com/911/911_misdials.html http://www.fcc.gov/cgb/consumerfacts/unint911.html

Answer (score 17):

According to the API, [ACTION_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL) will do what you need but not to emergency numbers, while [ACTION_DIAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL) will display a dialer with the dial prompt but allows to call emergency numbers.

I'm afraid there is no way to do what you want, for a good reason - to prevent misdials to emergency services. It's a precautionary measure.

Comment: Maybe some custom style ? For android >= 7.0 .