# how to call 911 without going through the Dialer user interface in android

Tags: android

Can you please help me find out how to call 911 without going through the Dialer user interface in Android?

I used the below code..but it's going through Dialer. I want to call directly to emergency number through my application.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); 
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:911")); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i used below code..but its going through dialer..but i want to call directly to emergency number through application

Comment: code here Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:911"));
  startActivity(intent);

Comment: Put your code in the question, not the comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dial Number Without Prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811680/dial-number-without-prompt)

Answer (score 3):

A search through existing questions provides the answer to this one as well as the two you asked yesterday: [Dial Number Without Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811680/dial-number-without-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add premission in mainfest file to use action_call.