# How to make a call directly?

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

when I use this code, first comes the dial pad screen with this number.

```
Intent dialintnt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:911"));
startActivityForResult(dialintnt, CALLING);
```

I don't want that screen. I want that when I click button directly calling that number.
So how can I call a number `onclick`?

Comment: (although, if you read the doc, you'll see that 911, being an emergency number (not outside the US, though), it can't be called directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13076308/2203164)

You will need add `CALL_PHONE` and `CALL_PRIVILEGED` permissions to manifest file.

Then the number can be called using:

```
Uri callUri = Uri.parse("tel://911");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,callUri);
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible. This is for user protection.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time. But may help someone else.
If you want to call directly, you should use [requestPermissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)) method.

**1.** Add this line to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

**2.** Define a class variable in the activity class:

```
private static Intent phoneCallIntent; //If use don't need a member variable is good to use a static variable for memory performance.
```

**3.** Add these lines to the **onCreate** method of the activity:

```
final String permissionToCall = Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE;
//Assume that you have a phone icon.
(findViewById(R.id.menuBarPhone)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view) {
        phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.callNumber))); //Uri.parse("tel:your number")
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainFrame.this, permissionToCall) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainFrame.this, new String[]{permissionToCall}, 1);
            return;
        }
        startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
    }
});
```

**4.** And for making a call immediately after clicking on **Allow button**, override [onRequestPermissionsResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])) method:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults){
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode == 1){
        final int permissionsLength = permissions.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < permissionsLength; i++) {
            if(grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

When a user give the permission, next time there will be no dialogue box and call will be make directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
   callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +phone_number));
   startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `ACTION_DIAL` to `ACTION_CALL`. 
Like this:

```
Intent dialintnt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:911"));
startActivityForResult(dialintnt, CALLING);
```

Answer (score 0):

Number has to be proper formatted as if you try with country code it will take you default dailer. i tested it on my app when i am using number as 198 call is happening directly and when i am using 9999999999 this will invoke the dailer so that user can correct the number by adding country code.

```
`val intent =  Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:+91987654310" ))
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
      startActivity(intent)`
```