# ionic2 phone call function how to call directly without showing anything

Tags: css, html, ionic2, ionic3

I want to call directly, do not showing prompt.

For me I used html5 `<a href>`, don't know how to set it as directly call when I click the button

**call.html**

```
  <div padding class="about-bottom">
    <a ion-button color="light" href="tel:1800889958">
      立即拨打
    </a>
  </div>
```

**call.scss**

```
.about-bottom {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F44336;
}
```

**call.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-call',
  templateUrl: 'call.html'
})
export class CallPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }
}
```

Comment: @sebaferreras  help please~~~

Comment: I just saw your comment with my name because I entered to this post, but user mentions on stack overflow does not work like this, I did not receive any notification. So I guess you can just mention someone in the comments (to really be notified) if he has already added an answer. Otherwise the mention won't notify anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible, at least in the existing versions of iOS.

Just like you can see in [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-10.3/):

> When a third party application invokes openURL: on a tel://,
>   facetime://, or facetime-audio:// URL, iOS displays a prompt and
>   requires user confirmation before dialing.

So that dialog will always be shown :(

**EDIT**

The same happens on Android. You can show the dial page with the number already entered, but you can't make the call directly. Since we're using Ionic (and not a native approach) we can ask the underlaying OS to handle the request, but we can't try to make the call directly.

Comment: On Android, does anything happen when you click that button?

Comment: When I click that button change to calling number page and the number showing in calling number there.

Comment: Just like you can see in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186106/how-to-make-a-call-directly): *It's not possible. This is for user protection.*. So I'm afraid that showing the call page with the number there is the only way to do it.

Comment: But android native can use 'ACTION_CALL' to derictly call without showing prompt, so ionic framework no some function like this one?

Comment: Yeah I know, but since we're using Ionic (and not a native approach) we can ask the underlaying OS to handle the request, but we can't try to call directly.

Comment: Glad to help :)