# Make a call using android app without showing the dialing prompt?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to make a call to a given number from my app. Sample picture attached.
[image: sample app screen]

And it should not show the dialing pad or dialing prompt. When I try it with following dialing prompt comes.

```
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:1234567890")));}
```

Dialing prompt is appears as follows

[image: Dialing prompt]

So how to dial directly from my app without showing the dialing prompt?

Comment: You can't, because the user's default dialer receives the intent.  And that's a good thing because it stops apps from making malicious calls.

Comment: :( so sad to hear it.... @Simon Thank you machan.

Comment: [Possible duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1811680/1050058)

Comment: @Yul : I need to make the call without the dialer. ACTION_CALL and ACTION_DIAL load the default dialer. So this is not a duplicate.

Comment: I don't see any much difference between `Dial Number Without Prompt` and `Make a call using android app without showing the dialing prompt?` . The basic is `call without show dialing promt`.

Comment: @Yul : Yep you point is correct. But answer of Dial Number Without Prompt does not solve my problem.