# How to call emergency number without accepting call?

Tags: java, android

I have a very specific problem. My app should implement calling emergency numbers (911, 112, etc.). But this must perform immediately, without pressing "Call" button. I've tried implement this via Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:" + getString(R.string.emd_emergency_number)));
startActivity(intent);
```

Finally, I see only dialer screen with number placed in number  section.
Does anybody know, how to resolve this problem?

Comment: You can't for emergency numbers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811680/dial-number-without-prompt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do that.

Calling emergency numbers require [CALL_PRIVILEGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PRIVILEGED) permission which, according to the documentation is :

> Not for use by third-party applications.

Comment: I've alredy applied such permissions as: '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />', but it doesn'twork.

Comment: but the documentation states that this permission cannot be granted to third-party application.

Comment: So, @njzk2, I cannot dial the emergency number through my app without accepting ?

Comment: you can only dial, not make the actual call. you can also refer to the documentation for ACTION_CALL : `this Intent cannot be used to call emergency numbers. Applications can dial emergency numbers using ACTION_DIAL, however.`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is usefull if let the user define a emergency number for himself(home,mum,wife,etc) instead of emergency number like 911,112.
Because other numbers can be called with:

```
public static final String ACTION_CALL 
Activity Action: Perform a call to someone specified by the data.

Input: If nothing, an empty dialer is started; else getData() is URI of a phone number    to be dialed or a tel: URI of an explicit phone number.

Output: nothing.

Note: there will be restrictions on which applications can initiate a call; most           applications should use the ACTION_DIAL.

Note: this Intent cannot be used to call emergency numbers. Applications can dial       emergency numbers using ACTION_DIAL, however.
Constant Value: "android.intent.action.CALL"
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL