# How to dial directly using the native dailer app in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my application i need to dial some phone numbers. But when i am trying this the prompt like the below picture is coming. How i can avoid this? I need to dial using the native dialer app only.

[image]

My code to make the call to 'phoneNo' is

```
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNo));
    startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: how to call such as screen shot? please show me make intent.

Comment: sorry...i have added my intent now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this which worked for me

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNo));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

ACTION_DIAL:

```
Activity Action: Dial a number as specified by the data. This shows a UI with 
the number being dialed, allowing the user to explicitly initiate the call.
```

Hope it helps you.

Ok i got this answer

According to the API, ACTION_CALL will do what you need but not to emergency numbers, while ACTION_DIAL will display a dialer with the dial prompt but allows to call emergency numbers.

I'm afraid there is no way to do what you want, for a good reason - to prevent misdials to emergency services. It's a precautionary measure.

From here [Dial Number Without Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811680/dial-number-without-prompt)

Ok and I think for what you wanted to perform you should atleast have one default Dialer in your Phone. Please check it.

Comment: Nope it calls number directly

Comment: ACTION_DIAL is showing just the dial pad only.. not making call.. I think as you said we can't do this. :(

Comment: Actually ACTION_CALL does what you want if there's default dialer being chosen by user. If not user chooses what he/she wants.